# How to use params in where query - Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ajax GET request that goes to a Rails controller, and returns a list of locations.

The user should be able to pass in as many params to search. I can't figure out how to do a where query with the params that are passed. The user can pass one param, or multiple params.

```
         return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/map_view_locations',
            data: {
                'location': {
                    'waitlist': true,
                }
            },
            success: function(locations)   {
                console.log(locations)
            }
          })
```

And in the controller:

```
 def map_view_locations
    puts 'params'
    location_params[:location]

    @locations = Location.where(location_params[:location]).includes(:food, :pricing)



    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: @locations.to_json(:include => [:food, :pricing])
      end
    end
  end
```

This returns all the locations, and doesn't take into consideration the params passed in. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: You send `{
                'location': {
                    'waitlist': true,
                }
            },` so you should use the `waitlist` boolean attribute on your where statement (I guess). Shouldn't it be something like `where('locations.waitlist = ?', params[:location][:waitlist])`?

Comment: But how can I write this without knowing what params are passed? Maybe they don't pass waitlist - maybe it's another param, or multiple params?

Comment: What kind of data types are they going to be? also a "dynamic" bunch of values? or just all of they boolean ones?

Comment: All of the above - why would the attribute type make a difference? Some attributes are booleans, strings or times. Is there a way to take the passed in params, and format them to be passed into the where query?

Answer (score 0):

Where clause maintains multiple parameters by hash e.g

```
where(param1: value1, param2: value2)
```

In your case I see you use `location_params` method.
Which I think looks similar to:

```
def location_params
  params.require(:location).permit(:waitlist)
end
```

So your `location_params` method return this hash:

```
{ waitlist: true }
```

When you call `location_params[:location]` it gives you `nil`, thereby `where` clause is ignored.

Try

```
Location.where(location_params)
```

Instead of

```
Location.where(location_params[:location])
```

I think it should work

Comment: Hi - you're correct. I had actually tried every variation, unable to understand why there is nothing coming back. This post has made me realize, there is a larger issue - all values are coming back a string `{"waitlist"=>"true"}`, and with respects to `waitlist`, that is a boolean and needs to be passed `true`. Is there a simpler way to pass the variables in the types they are? Thanks!

Comment: I think Rails automatically should convert these parameters to proper values.
So you can check it in your controller code
`puts location_params [:waitlist].class` and it should be `Boolean`

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe this will point you in the right direction?

```
property = params[:location].first
value = params[:location].last
Location.where("#{property} like ?", value).includes(:food, :pricing)
```